# Android device goes offline during debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

I start application from `Android Studio`. After that application starts on device, but a few seconds later device goes offline and disappear from `Android Studio`, it is shown as OFFLINE device with its serial number. Application is running on device, but no communication between IDE and device. USB connectivity is OK. I don't get error message.

Comment: See if starting the device before starting Studio resolves the issue. There may be a few tips here [Galaxy S7 Edge will not stay in software installation mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158205/galaxy-s7-edge-will-not-stay-in-software-installation-mode/160907?noredirect=1#comment206012_160907)

Comment: It can be a cable or usb port issue. Try a different cable and a different usb slot.